# What is the smallest vm available in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm interested in creating a VM in Azure and downloading to my own machine to use in Hyper-V. The past couple of attempts at creating a VM have resulted in a 127Gb image. Can anyone tell me what the absolute smallest windows vm available is and how I can choose this in set up. There doesn't seem to be any options for anything smaller than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use windows vms labeled as `smalldisk`, those will have 30gb os disk size. any linux vm will have 30gb os disk by default.

if using non portal, you can specify os disk size, I didnt ever try to downsize it below 30, but cant imagine why it wont work (unless there isn't enough space on the disk).

Comment: thanks - this is what i was looking for. i was always selecting images with Window 10 built in and these pre-made images all had larger disks. i see i can choose other images such as "[smalldisk] Windows Server 2016 Datacenter"

Comment: Downsizing by specifying the OS disk size does not work. Apparently, this option can only be used to increase the size: `The specified disk size 4 GB is smaller than the size of the corresponding disk in the VM image: 30 GB. This is not allowed. Please choose equal or greater size or do not specify an explicit size.`

Comment: you can create a smaller image

Answer (score 4):

Azure recently announced new B-series VM size, B1ls, which has the smallest memory and lowest cost among Azure VM instances. This offering is in response to customers who were looking for entry-level offerings. B1ls has 512 MiB of memory and 1 vCPU, and it costs only $0.0052 (US East) per hour.

B1ls is available only on Linux.

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/b-series-update-b1ls-is-now-available/